# Why I don't see the full line drawn between two points?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

In a `for` loop, I have two sets of data points `(x1,y1)` and `(x2,y2)`. I want to draw a line between them. For this, my code is given blow and response to this code is also attached.

```
import matplotlib.lines as mylines

fig, isc_check = plt.subplots()

for i,j in zip(IV_start_index,IV_start_index[1:]):  # This is simple code to access present and next element in a list        
    isc_act = module_allData_df['Current'].iloc[i:j-1].max()              
    isc_indx = module_allData_df['Current'].iloc[i:j-1].idxmax()         
    x = [module_allData_df['Voltage'].iloc[isc_indx],module_allData_df['Voltage'].iloc[j-1]]
    y = [isc_act,module_allData_df['Voltage'].iloc[j-1]]
    l = mlines.Line2D(x, y,color='r',marker='*')
    isc_check.add_line(l)
```

The output is given below:

[image]

My `x` data field has values ranging up to `8` and `y` data field has up to `15`. Interestingly, figure shows a small fraction of plot.

1. Please see the x and y axis limits. It is automatically showing 1.0 only but not the actual data? What could be wrong here?
2. In the plot, I actually want to draw different markers at both ends of lines. One marker at `(x1,y1)`, and other at `(x2,y2)`. In this plot, both points have the `*` marker. How to get different one at both?

Comment: Can you create a [mcve]?

Comment: Did you try setting the limits manually?